# Finitely generated Banach lattice $C(K)$ and partitions of unity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $E$ be a Banach lattice. A Banach sublattice $L$ of $E$ is called finitely generated if there exists a finite subset $F \subseteq E$ such that

$$L = \bigcap \{ \hat{L} \mid F \subseteq \hat L, \, \hat L \text{ is a Banach sublattice of E} \}.$$

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space and denote by $C(K)$ the Banach lattice of real valued continuous functions endowed with the supremum norm. Suppose that $C(K)$ is itself finitely generated.

Can it be inferred that $C(K)$ is generated by a partition of unity? Moreover, if this is the case, how does the cardinality of the smallest generating set compare to the cardinality of the generating partition of unity?

Comment: Let’s denote $\mathcal {S}$ the set of all $S$ of $C(K)$ that separate the points of $K$. Then  if I’m not wrong  $S\in \mathcal S$ if and only if $S\cup\{1\}$ generates $C(K)$ as a Banach sublattice (this is essentially a lemma  in the Stone-Weierstrass theorem). Therefore the question may be rephrased: given a finite $S\in \mathcal S$, can one build a finite $S’\in \mathcal S$ which is a partition of unity (and how  larger has to be)?

Comment: Also, a compact $K$ admits a set of $n$ functions that separate the points, iff it is homeomorphic to a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: But what do you ask on the partition of unity $\{\phi_i\}$? Just $\phi_i\ge0$ and $\sum_i\phi_i=1$ ?

Comment: Yes exactly. And with that I have just noticed how it must be done:

If the finite set $S \subseteq C(K)$ generates $C(K)$, then you define the $P$ to be the set containing $\alpha^{-1} \max(0, f)$, $\alpha^{-1} \max(0, - f)$ and the function $1 - \alpha ^{-1} g$, where $g = \sum_{f \in S} \lvert f \rvert$ and $\alpha = \lVert g \rVert_{\infty}$. Then the functions of $P$ are positive, lay in the sublattice generated by $S$ (namely $C(K)$) and sum up to $1$. Moreover, they separate the same set of points.

Comment: Thank you for all the great tips.

Comment: We may also say: and if $K$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, it can also be embedded as a subset of the standard simplex $$\Delta_n:=\{x\in[0,\infty)^{n+1}:\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i=1\}$$  So the $n+1$ coordinate functions $x_i$
 are a partition of unity